# KeyError: 'Symbols' when using a pivot table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I am trying to look up data in pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels import api as sm
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2016,12,2)
end = datetime.datetime.today()

df = web.get_data_yahoo(['F', '^GSPC'], start, end)
```

if i unstack the data here

```
df.unstack()
```

i get the following:

```
Attributes  Symbols  Date      
Adj Close   F        2016-12-01    1.011866e+01
                     2016-12-02    9.963994e+00
                     2016-12-05    1.012680e+01
                     2016-12-06    1.022449e+01
                     2016-12-07    1.063152e+01
                                       ...     
Volume      ^GSPC    2019-11-22    3.226780e+09
                     2019-11-25    3.511530e+09
                     2019-11-26    4.595590e+09
                     2019-11-27    3.033090e+09
                     2019-11-29    1.743020e+11
Length: 9048, dtype: float64
```

df has the following data:

```
Attributes  Adj Close   Close   High    Low Open    Volume
Symbols F   ^GSPC   F   ^GSPC   F   ^GSPC   F   ^GSPC   F   ^GSPC   F   ^GSPC
Date                                                
2015-02-11  12.216836   2068.530029 16.250000   2068.530029 16.309999   2073.479980 16.010000   2057.989990 16.080000   2068.550049 34285300.0  3.596860e+09
2015-02-12  12.299535   2088.479980 16.360001   2088.479980 16.450001   2088.530029 16.299999   2069.979980 16.340000   2069.979980 23738800.0  3.788350e+09
2015-02-13  12.254424   2096.989990 16.299999   2096.989990 16.360001   2097.030029 16.190001   2086.699951 16.330000   2088.780029 19954600.0  3.527450e+09
2015-02-17  12.111583   2100.340088 16.110001   2100.340088 16.299999   2101.300049 16.000000   2089.800049 16.209999   2096.469971 44362300.0  3.361750e+09
2015-02-18  12.186762   2099.679932 16.209999   2099.679932 16.330000   2100.229980 16.059999   2092.149902 16.160000   2099.159912 22812700.0  3.370020e+09
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2019-11-22  8.890000    3110.290039 8.890000    3110.290039 8.900000    3112.870117 8.770000    3099.260010 8.800000    3111.409912 34966700.0  3.226780e+09
2019-11-25  9.000000    3133.639893 9.000000    3133.639893 9.010000    3133.830078 8.870000    3117.439941 8.900000    3117.439941 30580900.0  3.511530e+09
2019-11-26  9.010000    3140.520020 9.010000    3140.520020 9.020000    3142.689941 8.910000    3131.000000 8.980000    3134.850098 30093800.0  4.595590e+09
2019-11-27  9.100000    3153.629883 9.100000    3153.629883 9.150000    3154.260010 9.020000    3143.409912 9.030000    3145.489990 37396100.0  3.033090e+09
2019-11-29  9.060000    3140.979980 9.060000    3140.979980 9.100000    3150.300049 9.030000    3139.340088 9.040000    3147.179932 13096200.0  1.743020e+11
1210 rows × 12 columns
```

To find the data in df i am using a pivot_table:

```
df.pivot_table(values = 'Adj Close', index = 'Date', columns = 'Symbols')
```

but i am getting an error:

```
KeyError: 'Symbols'
```

Why am i getting this error?

Comment: are there extra spaces in the column names?

Comment: The error message states that there is no column named 'Symbols' in the table. Your task as this point would be to figure out why that is, given that something that "seems" like "Symbols" seems to be present. Note that it's generally better to assume that the code doesn't lie, and check all your assumptions.

Comment: @sathyz I don't think so

Comment: Suggestion: print or assign `df.columns` and go from there.

Comment: `MultiIndex([('Adj Close',     'F'),
            ('Adj Close', '^GSPC'),
            (    'Close',     'F'),
            (    'Close', '^GSPC'),
            (     'High',     'F'),
            (     'High', '^GSPC'),
            (      'Low',     'F'),
            (      'Low', '^GSPC'),
            (     'Open',     'F'),
            (     'Open', '^GSPC'),
            (   'Volume',     'F'),
            (   'Volume', '^GSPC')],
           names=['Attributes', 'Symbols'])`

Comment: Should this be treated as a dictionary?

Comment: @newcoder there is no column named Symbols. It's only a "name" given to the MultiIndex item whose values represent columns.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh How can i get the  value of 'Adj Close', '^GSPC'` on a date?

Comment: take a look at [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html)

Comment: What do you expect to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you already have a multiindex with what you need, you don't have to pivot.

```
>>> df['Adj Close'].head()
Symbols             F        ^GSPC
Date                              
2016-12-01  10.297861  2191.080078
2016-12-02  10.140451  2191.949951
2016-12-05  10.306145  2204.709961
2016-12-06  10.405562  2212.229980
2016-12-07  10.819797  2241.350098
>>>
```

Comment: I just want to do it because i have conceptual problems with understanding of multi-index dataframe. I want to know how i can do it the pivot way! Thanks :)